# How to initialize a new Spark Context and executors number on YARN from RStudio

Tags: r, apache-spark, rstudio, rstudio-server, sparkr

I am working with [`SparkR`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sparkr.html).

I am able to set Spark Context on YARN with desired number of `executors` and `executor-cores` with such command:

```
spark/bin/sparkR --master yarn-client --num-executors 5 --executor-cores 5
```

Now I am trying to initialize a new Spark Context but from RStudio which is more comfortable to work with than a regular command line.

I figured out that to do this I'll need to use `sparkR.init()` function. There is an option `master` which I set to `yarn-client` but how to specify `num-executors` or `executor-cores`? This is where I stacked

```
library(SparkR, lib.loc = "spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/R/lib")

sc <- sparkR.init(sparkHome = "spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/",
                  master = "yarn-client")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing `sparkEnvir` argument for `sparkR.init` should work:

```
sparkEnvir <- list(spark.num.executors='5', spark.executor.cores='5')

sc <- sparkR.init(
    sparkHome = "spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.4/", 
    master = "yarn-client",
    sparkEnvir = sparkEnvir)
```

Comment: Why have we to do sparkContext, sqlContext or HiveContext ?